# Extremely bizzare issue with Bullet physics

Tags: c++, bulletphysics

I am using bullet physics with my project. I used to compile it and my project with Visual C++, and everything worked fine. But I'm getting an extremely bizzare issue when now using Code::Blocks instead. When I switched over, I rebuilt the bullet physics library with the standard MinGW compiler bundled with the program. When compiling my project it did work at first. But after maybe 3 recompiles of my own project, for some reason kinematic bodies do not seem to interact with other bodies at all. The issue is fixed if I recompile bullet physics again and replace the binaries (strange, considering they should be binary identical). I can then recompile my project for 3-5 times again before it starts happening again. How do I even start debugging this?

Comment: "strange, considering they should be binary identical", you can test that, run a checksum on the binary files. As a first guess, you have some global variable not initialized properly. I doubt it that the library is the issue, did you try to figure out what makes the bug occur?

Comment: 19 times out of 20 this is because I thought I was compiling to a particular output library file when, in fact, I was compiling to some other file and running old stale content